# ansible nested dictionary processing

Tags: python, ansible

I have this below task,

```
    - debug:
    msg: "Here: {{ item['containers'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ container_matrix['results'] }}"
```

which returns a dictionary with container name and its start up arguments. 
like : {"container-1":{"docker_run":"docker run -p  80:80 nginx", "env_file":"config1.env"}, 
        "container-2":{"docker_run":"docker run -p  8080:80 nginx", "env_file":"config2.env"}

However I actually want to extract the container name and its env_file,

```
container_1 -> config1.env
container-2  -> config2.env
```

I tried several things, and none of the methods seem to work.

```
- debug:
    msg: "Here: {{ item }}"
  with_dict: "{{ container_matrix['results'].'containers'] }}"
```

is failing too.

can someone guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Given *"a dictionary with container name and its start up arguments. like"*

```
containers:
  "container-1": {"docker_run":"docker run -p 80:80 nginx", "env_file":"config1.env"}
  "container-2": {"docker_run":"docker run -p 8080:80 nginx", "env_file":"config2.env"}
```

The tasks

```
    - set_fact:
        mydata: "{{ containers|
                    dict2items|
                    json_query('[].{name: key, env_file: value.env_file}') }}"
    - debug:
        var: mydata
```

give

```
    "mydata": [
        {
            "env_file": "config1.env", 
            "name": "container-1"
        }, 
        {
            "env_file": "config2.env", 
            "name": "container-2"
        }
    ]
```